# Play sound in Sequence in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, simpleaudioengine

how to play sound in cocos2d in sequence does any body have any idea for example i have three sound like

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.OrderOneSound]];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.WithSound]];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.OrderTwoSound]];
```

this is the code of sound effect play how can i play when one is stop and then another play after that

Comment: You can use the CCSequence for play effect for the Sound! It would be better way!

Answer (score 9):

```
CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions: 
                                [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void)
                                 { 
                                     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.OrderOneSound]];
                                 }],
                                [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3],
                                [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void)
                                 { 
                                     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.WithSound]];
                                 }],
                                [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3],
                                [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void)
                                 { 
                                     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[CommanMethods GetCompleteSoundPath:objplate.OrderTwoSound]];
                                 }],
                                nil];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

this way can solve your problem, but only drawback is you have to insert delay time by yourself. hope it work for your situation.